# Jenkins Custom Column For View That Can Display Any Text From A Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

new to Jenkins, but got it setup and working.  Looking at Plugins, but don't see one where a column can be added to a view that will display any text that could be suppled by a job / job script.

Maybe I am missing it, but how can we display a col that displays any text from a job?

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View

Comment: What text would you like to display? Any implies that it needs to be persisted somewhere/somehow...

Comment: Well, any text, not something that is "part of" Jenkins.  Could be from a file, could be from an Environment Variable from the script, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure a such a plugin would provide much benefit to a lot of people, and perhaps this is why it was not implemented. If nothing on the [existing plugins that add various columns](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-ListViewcolumnplugins) list fits your needs, I guess you could take a look at their sources the and build your own.

Comment: Looks like that is what I might have to do.  To be very specific, the build script knows about the exact version of the build and would like to display that in a column.